# VsCode how to add webview to activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to understand how to add WebView inside the sidebar (activity bar) on VsCode.

In the official examples, they just put the webview inside the panel. But, I want to know, how to add my icon to the activity bar and how to show my webview when I click on my Icon.

If you share something useful that will be appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere. Using [Calico Colors — Webview View API Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample)  example I managed to display on sidebar.

Comment: The icon in the activity bar is created when you create a `ViewContainer`, in there you create Views and you need to add a `WebviewView`, see the example at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview